# Angular2 AoT Compiler no ngfactory files?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot

When using ngc in place of tsc, or when using AotPlugin from @ngtools/webpack, ngfactory files should be generated for each angular module.
But in my case the ngc succeeds silently yet no files are generated.

Can you please give me a guidance how to even investigate that if the ngc does not print any message?

I tried with typescript@2.1.6 and 2.0.2
With @angular 2.3.1 and 2.4.7.
The result is the same.

Here's my tsconfig and webpack config, too. In both cases (run webpack or run ngc) it won't create the files.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "diagnostics": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "./compiled",
    "rootDir": "./"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "include": [ "typings" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/module#AppModule",
    "gendir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true,
    "debug": true,
    "trace": true,
    "generateCodeForLibraries": true
  }
}
```

and the webpack file:

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='Watch - Development' />
var AotPlugin = require("@ngtools/webpack").AotPlugin;

var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var basePath = path.join(__dirname, "wwwroot");

module.exports = {
    context: basePath,
    entry: {
        main: ["./app/main.ts"],
        productModule: "./app/components/product-module",
        adminModule: "./app/components/admin-module"
'rxjs/add/operator/map', 'rxjs/add/operator/delay']
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "wwwroot/built"),
            filename: "[name].bundle.js",
            sourceMapFilename: "[name].bundle.js",
            publicPath: "built/"
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    loader: "html-loader",
                    query: {
                        minimize: true,
                        ignoreCustomFragments: [/\{\{.*?}}/],
                        removeAttributeQuotes: false,
                        caseSensitive: true,
                        customAttrSurround: [ [/#/, /(?:)/], [/\*/, /(?:)/], [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/] ],
                        customAttrAssign: [ /\)?\]?=/ ] ,
                        root: basePath,
                        attrs: false // ['img:src', 'link:href']
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    loaders: ["@ngtools/webpack"]
                }//,
               // { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader?root=." }
            ]
        },
        externals: {
            "jquery": "jQuery"
        },
        devtool: false,
        plugins: [
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.json",
                entryModule: "app/module#AppModule"
            }),
           // new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                //filename: "[name].c.bundle.js"//, 
                names: ["main"]
            })
            //,
            , new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
                minimize: true,
                acorn: true,
                angular: true,
                beautify: false,
                compress: {
                    properties: true,
                    sequences: true,
                    dead_code: true,
                    drop_debugger: true,
                    unsafe_comps: true,
                    conditionals: true,
                    comparisons: true,
                    evaluate: true,
                    booleans: true,
                    keep_fargs: false,
                    loops: true,
                    unsafe: true,
                    angular: true,
                    unused: true,
                    cascade: true,
                    hoist_funs: true,
                    join_vars: true,
                    warnings: false
                },
                output: {
                    comments: false
                }
            })
        ]

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of open issues about this when using typscript version 2.1.x

Use Typescript 2.0.2 for now.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11689

Another reason might be that there's a typo in your `"gendir": "aot",` it should be `genDir`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I already tried 2.0.2 but as I sometimes have issues with source of use of packages (I could downgrade local typescript but something might be stil using global ) then I will check again. The genDir thing, thanks for that too. I wouldn't be able catch that :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is @ngtools/webpack doesn't generate those files.

@ngtools/webpack handle those files in-memory and generate one file.